# Animation from Style Trigger in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I was trying to decipher why an animation would not start from a Style Trigger but would start from a Button event.  Here is a more simplified example:

```xml
<StackPanel> 
        <p:Plane Width="350" Height="250" x:Name="_plane" RotationY="1">
            <p:Plane.Content >
                <Border Background="Green" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" Height="30" Width="30"></Border>
            </p:Plane.Content>
            <p:Plane.BackContent>
                <Border Background="Red" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" Height="30" Width="30"></Border>
            </p:Plane.BackContent> 
            <p:Plane.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test}" Value="true" >
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY" SpeedRatio="1">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="360" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </p:Plane.Style>
        </p:Plane>
        <Button Content="Spin" Click="Spin_Click" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private bool test = true;
    public bool Test
    {
        get { return test;  }
        set { test = value; }
    }

    private void Spin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var spin = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames { RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever, SpeedRatio = 1 };
        spin.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame { Value = 0, KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) });
        spin.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame { Value = 360, KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) });

        PropertyPath pp = new PropertyPath(Plane.RotationYProperty);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(spin, _plane);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(spin, pp);

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(spin);
        sb.Begin(); 
    }
```

When you remark out the  section and pressed the button the animation would play.  Unremarking the tag would cause the shape to disappear all together.

The key to the issue is in the accepted answer, which was genius!

Comment: Could you add your method signature to the code? Also, debugging can be really helpful. Put a breakpoint in your method and see if the code jumps into it.

Comment: could you post whole xaml for the element?

Comment: @pushpraj Updated code and xaml per request.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Updaetd per request

Comment: Could you post the Xaml for your staticresource? I think it might not trigger there.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Converter code added.  I put a conditional breakpoint on the return blink for when its true and I see the value coming back.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with animation, do check if `Value` property is being resolved correctly, do have expected value and do provide change notification if necessary. see if there is any data error in output pane while debugging.

Comment: @pushpraj I put a break in the method that returned value previously, but I also changed it for now to always be true.  The animation is doing "something" because it makes rectangles disappear completely.

Comment: is `conv:Plane` a public component, could you share the source link, may we try here.

Comment: @pushpraj it was too big to post so I zipped the class and the styles and posted it at http://www.joshuaterry.com/plane.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the animation but with the style itself

As I can see in the code that you have a `Style` defined for the `Plane` class in resources which gives appearance to this plane object

however in element's context you've defined another style for the purpose of applying animation so it effectively override the original style hence leaving no appearance

so in order to fix the issue you need to derive the contextual style from the original style using the `BasedOn` attribute and then add trigger etc

example

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type conv:Plane}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type conv:Plane}}">
    ... trigger, animation stuff etc
```

this will create a new style while deriving the original.

Comment: You sir are Brilliant!  If I may ask, how were you able to discern this?  Is there a tool that shows you what styles value are being applied at a given time?

Comment: The question did not mention anything about the existing style and the Plane class was also unknown to me so it was pretty difficult to guess just by looking at the question. However in code, I saw a style defined for plane class in app.xaml and then I saw another style for the same class in element's declaration and the problem was clear. Secondly you may use tools like `Snoop UI` or `WPF Inspactor` to analyse the visual tree of your wpf applications and also identify from where the values for any property is coming from. happy coding :)